# Is it possible to display "<" or ">" in generated XML source using XStreamMarshaller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have been trying to use XStreamMarshaller to generate XML output in my Java Spring project. The XML I am generating has CDATA values in the element text. I am manually creating this CDATA text in the command object like this:

```
 f.setText("<![CDATA[cdata-text]]>");
```

The XStreamMarshaller generated the element(text-data below is an alias) as:

```
<text-data><![CDATA[cdata-text]]></text-data>
```

The above XML display is as expected (Please ignore the back slash in the above element name: **forum formatting**). But when I do a **View Source** on the XML output generated I see this for the element: `<text-data>&lt;![CDATA[cdata-text]]&gt;</text-data>`.

**Issue:**

As you can see the less than and greater than characters have been replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the View Source. I need my client to read the source and identify CDATA section from the XML output which it will not in the above scenario.

Is there a way I can get the XStreamMarshaller to escape special characters in the text I provided?

I have set the encoding of the Marshaller to ISO-8859-1 but that does not work either. If the above cannot be done by XStreamMarshaller can you please suggest alternate marshallers/unmarshallers that can do this for me?

// Displaying my XML and View Source as suggested by Paŭlo Ebermann below:

**XML View (as displayed in IE):**

```
An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'http://localhost:8080/file-service-framework/fil...

Los t
```

**View Source:**

```
<service id="file-text"><text-data>&lt;![CDATA[
Los túneles a través de las montañas hacen más fácil viajar por carretera.
]]&gt;</text-data></service>
```

Thanks you very much.

Comment: From the little amount that I know of xml / I have had this issue in flex as well the &lt; and &gt; are in fact the escaping of the special characters < and > since using them explicitly would treat them as just < or >. I'm sorry that this is no help, hopefully someone else has some ideas or knows whether what you're looking for is possible

Comment: `<` and `>` are not allowed in text sections of xml, you must use `&lt;` and `&gt;`. You'd create a new xml node if you were able to use those braces. If that is what you seek to do, search for something like `f.addNode`..

Comment: @LumpN They are allowed in CDATA,  [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-cdsection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating CDATA sections is the task of your XML-generating library, not of its client. So you should simply have to write

```
f.setText("cdata-text");
```

and then the library can decide whether to use `<![CDATA[`...`]]>` or the `&lt;`-escaping for its contents. **It should make no difference for the receiver**.

---

**Edit:**

Looking at your output, it looks right (apart from the CDATA) - here you must work on your input, as said.

If IE throws an error here, most probably you don't have declared the right encoding.

I don't really know much about the Spring framework, but the encoding used by the Marshaller should be the same encoding as the encoding sent in either the HTTP header (`Content-Type: ... ;charset=...`) or the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="..." ?>` XML prologue (these two should not differ, too).

I would recommend `UTF-8` as encoding everywhere, as this can represent all characters, not only the Latin-1 ones.

Comment: Thanks for the information Paulo. The <![CDATA[...]]> in f.setText is part of the input. I am inputting it manually above as an example. In actual scenario it is not in my control. But I did check on my client side XML libraries and they seem to handle &lt; and &gt; and convert them to < and >. So the View Source is not an issue. 

But I noticed that there are some special characters such as "ú","ñ" and "á" that throw an error in my XML view itself but the "View Source" looks fine. Is there any settings that I need to change on my end to XStreamMarshaller to display special characters.

Comment: For "special characters", make sure they are encoded in the same way as declared. If you have them working in your Java string, they should work in the XML, too. (You may want to post the complete resulting XML here for comparison - here meaning edit your question.) Of course, it could be that your "XML view" is stupid (= not XML-conform) and simply only understands ASCII or such.

Comment: The View I am using is org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView and I pass the XStreamMarshaller in the constructor to the view. Do you receommend any other view other than the above? I will edit my post to show my XML and the Browser view source right away.

Comment: Paŭlo, Thank you very much for the continuous help and response. It seems that Firefox is able to render the XML document correctly even without the XML version and encoding headers. The above code snippets works in IE if I add the headers to the XML output generated by XStreamMarshallers as XStream is not designed to output XML headers. The XML handlers are able to parse the "View Source" without the headers so I believe my clients will work regardless of the headers.